# How to use align.el and `align-current` to align let forms easily

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to align

```lisp
(let ((blah  foo)
      (asdfasdf asdasdfafd))
  (message "foo"))
```

to be

```
(let ((blah     foo)
      (asdfasdf asdasdfafd))
  (message "foo"))
```

In other words, the let bound values should be aligned properly.

If I select the first two lines, then this function works:

```
(defun align-try-1 (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (align-regexp beg end "^\\s-*+\\(?:(let\\S-*\\|\\)\\s-*(+\\S-+\\(\\s-+\\)" 1 1 nil))
```

However, I want to make align-current work by hooking into the align
machinery.  i.e. with the point anywhere in the first two lines, the correct alignment should happen without affecting the third line.

Answer (score 0):

You can't scan for sexps in regexps, since they are scanned recursively.

I wrote this thing without align(i'm not really sure if it can be done with align function, but just sticking to sexp moves, gotos and insertions makes it easier for me).

```
(defun align-try-1 (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (goto-char beg)
  (let ((endmarker (move-marker (make-marker) end)))
    (catch :break
      (while t
        (catch :continue
          (let ((actual-begin (re-search-forward "(\\([[:space:]\n]*\\)let\\([[:space:]\n]*\\)(" endmarker t))
                 (max-column  0))
            (unless actual-begin (throw :break nil))
            (when (or (in-string-p)
                    (eq (get-char-property actual-begin 'face) 'font-lock-comment-face))
              (throw :continue nil))
            (while (and (< (point) endmarker) (ignore-errors (down-list) t) (ignore-errors (forward-sexp) t))
              (when (looking-at "[[:space:]\n]+") (delete-region (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)))
              (insert " ")
              (when (< max-column (current-column))
                (setq max-column (current-column)))
              (backward-up-list)
              (forward-sexp))
            (goto-char actual-begin)
            (while (and (< (point) endmarker) (ignore-errors (down-list) t) (ignore-errors (forward-sexp) t))
              (when (looking-at "[[:space:]\n]+") (delete-region (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)))
              (dotimes (i (- max-column (current-column))) (insert " "))
              (backward-up-list)
              (forward-sexp))
            (goto-char actual-begin)
            ))))))
```

By the way, where do you use it?

**Update:** added checks for being in comment or string.

**Update:** removed enforce-formatting thingy, because it's buggy and don't needed in original question.

Comment: This question was an exercise in understanding `align` machinery better.   I can hack together a function that works with `align-regexp`, but wasn't sure how to hook it up so `align-current` works.